# Extra terms in continuously compounded superannuation

Tags: finance

Adam opens a superannuation account with a deposit of $1000$ and intends to deposit money at a rate of $1000$ per year for the next 25 years. Interest is paid at the rate of $0.1$% pa, compounded continuously. If A is the amount after $t$ years, prove that $$A = 11000e^{0.1t}-10000$$

I simply have $A = 1000e^{0.1t}$. Obviously this is wrong but I cant see where or why anything would be subtracted in this case. To try and account for the deposits, I set up a recursive balance which I found the sum of the geometric progression to be $A = 1000\left[\frac{(e^{0.1})^{t+1} -1}{e^{0.1} -1}\right]$

It cam from $A_0=1000$

$A_1 = 1000e^{0.1}+1000$...

.
.
.
$A_t =1000\left[\frac{(e^{0.1})^{t+1} -1}{e^{0.1} -1}\right]$

Please help

Comment: Your formula $1000e^{0.1t}$ is the amount resulting from the initial deposit (1000) and interest on it. It doesn't take into account the additional planned deposits of 1000 per year for the next 25 years.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(\tau)$ denote the balance at time $\tau$.

Over the interval $[\tau, \tau+ \Delta \tau]$ we have

$$A(\tau + \Delta \tau ) \approx A(\tau) (1 + i \Delta \tau) + \alpha \Delta \tau,$$

where $i$ is the interest rate and $\alpha$ is the deposit rate (per annum).

Rearranging we get

$$\frac{A(\tau + \Delta \tau ) - A(\tau)}{\Delta \tau} = i A(\tau) + \alpha$$

Taking the limit as $\Delta \tau \to 0$, we get the differential equation for the account balance

$$\frac{dA}{d \tau} = i A + \alpha$$

With the initial balance $A(0) = A_0$ we solve by separation of variables to obtain

$$\int_{A_0}^{A(t)}\frac{d A}{\alpha + iA} = \int_0^t  \,d \tau, \\\implies \frac{1}{i}\log \frac{\alpha +i A(t)}{\alpha + i A_0} = t, \\ \implies A(t) = (\alpha /i + A_0)e^{it} - \alpha/i$$

Substituting parameters, we obtain

$$A(t) = 11000e^{0.1t}- 10000$$